# finite generation and indeterminates

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

It's a soft, maybe naive question.

Let $G\le \text{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z}[x])$ be a subgroup. Can we prove the finite generation of $G$ by evaluating $x$ at some (possibly infinite) class of complex numbers?

For example, for every $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, define the evaluating maps at $x=m$, $\phi_m:\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z}[x])\to\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$. If for each $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\phi_m(G)$ is finitely generated, then can we conclude $G$ is finitely generated? What if we use $\phi_{1/m}$, instead of $\phi_m$? Surely, if the "evaluating set" contains a transcendental number, then the problem becomes trivial(thus, we should use a countable set, to make sense). Does the answer vary depending on the dimension $n$?

Note that this question may be generalized to $n+1$-indeterminate cases; can we determine the f.g.ness of $H\le \text{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_n,y])$ by checking the f.g.ness of a family of evaluated groups in $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_n])$? However, at first, I'm interested in the simplest cases, written above.

Comment: Suslin(1977) proved that $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb {Z}[x]) $ itself, for every $n\ge 3$, is finitely generated. However, $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb {Z}[x]) $ is not f.g. and a subgroup of $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb {Z}[x]) $, thus it is a trivial counterexample when we take $\mathbb{Z} $ as the evaluating set.